# How to access component method inside my ios delegate class

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

How to access a method from the app component to main.ts file??

I am developing android and ios mobile application using Nativescript angular. I have created a ios delegate class for application onResume. I want to call the native script class component method inside of my ios delegate class. Help me achieve the functionality

```
My ios delegate class:
import { android, ios, AndroidApplication, AndroidActivityBundleEventData } from "tns-core-modules/application";
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";



    class MyDelegate1 extends UIResponder implements UIApplicationDelegate{


        constructor(private sharedClass:sharedClass) {
            super();
        }

        public static ObjCProtocols =[UIApplicationDelegate];

        applicationWillEnterForeground(application:UIApplication):void{
                application.notify({
                    eventName:"SampleFunction",
                    object:application
                }) 


        }

        applicationDidEnterBackground(application:UIApplication):void{
            console.log("applicationDidEnterBackground"+application);
        }
    }
```

My nativescript component class

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(){}

      ngOnInit(){ }

       SampleFunction(){
         console.log("Will call from ios delegate class");
        }

}
```

Help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not suppose to call the Component method directly from your delegate. A better practice would be, firing an event on application object and listening to the same form your Angular component.

FYI, events like pause / resume are supported out of the box.

**Edit:**

To fire event on application module,

```
   import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";

    applicationWillEnterForeground(application:UIApplication):void{
        application.notify({
            eventName: "YourEventName",
            object: application,
            // Add any additional params that can be accessed from the event object by listener callback
        });         
    }
```

Comment: Thank you manoj..How to use this event inside my component class?

Comment: Just like any other event in application module (pause, resume etc.,) Just use your event's name

Comment: I am edited my code please check it was correct or wrong..this is not working properly....help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you assign the custom app delegate? I see only the implementation. Also I already told you the foreground event is supported out of the box.

Comment: Where to assign custom app delegate class?

Comment: Just refer the documentation, it's explained much better there.

Answer (score 0):

**ViewChild** might be one of the ways you are looking for.

In your **app.component.ts**,

```
import {ViewChild} from "@angular/core";

export class AppComponent{

   @ViewChild('templateReferenceVariableName') reference : YourComponent;

   reference.methodYouWantedToAccess();
}
```

In your **app.component.html**,

```
<html>
    <your-component #templateReferenceVariableName > </your-component>
</html>
```

The #templateReferenceVariableName acts a the link between the **.ts** and **.html**

P.S: you can replace the name with your like.